# Alien deletes the .deb generated before I can install it

Tags: deb, package-management, rpm

After I "alien" a **.rpm** file, i see `freego_4.5-2_i386.deb`, generated but can't find the file afterwatds.

Then trying `alien -i` results in an error message stating the .deb file couldn't be found
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: solved by using a x86_64 instead of i586 mandriva rpm

Answer (score 3):

solved by using a x86_64 instead of i586 mandriva rpm